# clientX and clientY issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>clientX\clientY example</title>

<script>
function showCoords(evt){
  alert(
    "clientX value: " + evt.clientX + "\n" +
    "clientY value: " + evt.clientY + "\n"
  );
}
</script>
</head>

<body onmousedown="showCoords(event)" onunload="showCoords(event)">
<p>To display the mouse coordinates click anywhere on the page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE, When I click on the Browser refresh button, I'm getting the ClientY value in negative. Why?
Also, in other browsers, I'm not getting alert box on Browser Refresh button...Any help would be appreciated....Thanks...

Comment: For ur first question : During refresh, u may place your mouse arrow near url bar, thats why it is showing as Y-axis in negative..

Comment: For your second question, what would you like to achieve during page load.?  onunload wont work in all browsers..

Comment: I want to redirect the user to Login page when Y value is negative (that is on Browser Refresh button).

Comment: whenever you are refreshing, u need to redirect to login screen? Am i correct.

Comment: Yes, but only when Browser Refresh button is clicked.